# Javascript integer beginning with zero

Tags: javascript

I have a question about how javascript parses integers beginning with zero(for example a bank account number). Simple example below from chrome dev tools.

```js
var zeroTest = 022;
//undefined

zeroTest
// 18
```

why does this become 18? Is there a robust interpretation that can be used for any input beginning with zero to find the resulting value when var is accessed?

Comment: Bank account numbers are not integers. Use a string.

Comment: In JavaScript, any number starting with 0 is considered as an octal number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading zero in literal indicates that you want to use an octal (base 8) number.

Comment: Just a pointer, you should not answer a duplicate. If you read a question which is very basic, there is a high possibility that it has been answered before and you should search for such posts and share its link in comment. This way someone can close question